# How to play videos on HTML page with cross-browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

Our application has a lot of videos to play on HTML page, at the beginning. I tried both `object` and `video` tags to play these videos, but I found the problem of cross-browser compatibility, **these 2 tags can't work well on IE 6/7/8**. Absolutely, we are not able to develop a new video player to do it, and I guess video playing is a very common case for Java EE development, so I want to ask if there is any good way for us to play videos with good cross-browser compatibility.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try jplayer which is compatible with Windows : IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 and also works well on Opera mini and android browser.

```
http://www.jplayer.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like the following will allow you to play videos on most browsers:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="myVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
   <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="player.swf?videoUrl=myVideo.mp4">
      <param name="movie" value="player.swf?videoUrl=mVideo.mp4">
   </object>
</video>
```

In this case `player.swf` is a Flash player such as those available with popular video players like [MediaElementJs](http://mediaelementjs.com/) (which of course you could simply use instead) which plays MP4 files. Or if you have a Flash `flv` file you can play it here without the `player.swf`.

You should also include the [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) file so that the `video` element is not ignored by these older browsers.

But you may have tried all this, so an example of the code you tried that didn't work would be useful to see.